# How do I upload a zip file to Amazon S3 using Javascript (Angular framework)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the following code:

```
params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket.com',
    Key: zipPath
    },
s3 = new AWS.S3();
params.Body = zipFile;
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        logger.info('Upload error: ' + err);
    } else {
        logger.info('Uploaded: ' + String(data));
    }
});
```

When I change the body contents to a string (i.e 'Hello'), it will upload perfectly fine. However, when I try to attach a zip file, it is not working. Any ideas? I am really new to uploading files and can't seem to find any answers online.

Error that I get: Upload error: Error: Cannot determine length of [object Object]

EDIT: the zip contains images.

Comment: what is zipPath? if its a path to a file obviously u get an error. key must be a name e.g. myfile.zip

Comment: also add ContentType: file.type to ur param

Comment: zipPath is a name like Myfile.zip.

Comment: Sadly, it is still not working even though I added:    params = {
    Bucket: 'PATH',
    Key: myfile.zip,
    ContentType: 'zip'
   },

Comment: check this :  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html <--under uploading a file section

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Include this in your html header:

HTML file:

```
<input type="file" id="file-chooser" /> 
<button id="upload-button">Upload to S3</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Javascript file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket'}});
  var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
  var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var file = fileChooser.files[0];
    if (file) {
      results.innerHTML = '';

  var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
      bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        results.innerHTML = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.';
      });
    } else {
      results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
    }
  }, false);
</script>
```